# Can I make the mouse hairpin in the terminal more visible?

Tags: terminal

It often takes me a while to find the mouse crosshair when working with Terminal.app. Is there a way to make it more visible?

Comment: Do you want to customize the mouse cursor (while you're moving it around), or the text cursor (that shows you where you are in some text)?

Comment: The mouse pointer that appears when I am over the Terminal.app window. I would like it to be something more visible than a crosshair.

Comment: To be more clear, this is largely a problem if you have the terminal background set to black, or otherwise a very dark color.  Unlike the arrow pointer, the text select hairpin doesn't have a border color of white to make it visible against any background.

Comment: Did you find a solution yourself? :) It's very irritating especially with an external main monitor, the pointer gets lost on the side monitor

Comment: @KaanSoral, nah, I just switched to a light background in iTerm to make it more visible

Comment: Well it seems it was previously very easy, yet that method no longer works: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107737/i-beam-cursor-color-in-maverickss-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an app available to download called [Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com/) which will put green markers around your cursor if you press a hotkey.  That might help you but I don't know if it's still a working program under current OS X releases.

Comment: Appears to be broken in Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

I've started having this problem also, not sure if it started happening after i got a retina screen or upgraded to mavericks, or im just getting old. My suggestion is to try [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) which have a bit more visible "hairpin".

Comment: I'm having this issue after upgrading to Yosimite from Mountain Lion. It is definitely dimmer. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the blinking cursor, then you need to go into the terminal preferences. Here's a picture to help you better understand

[image: Terminal Prefences]

Comment: Thanks, Slick. But I meant the OSX pointer, it switches to a hairpin when you move it through the Terminal.app window, then it goes back to being an arrow.